# Check whether the selected row has a checked check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the selected row has a column check box checked?
I can get the column innerHTML which says                                       `<input type="checkbox">` but how to check if its checked or not.

I want to see if the CB is checked?

```
var l_iNoOfRows=$("#imageResultsList tr").length;

for(var i=1;i<=l_iNoOfRows;i++){
      var l_oSelectedRow =$("#imageResultsList tr")[i]
      var l_sCbColumn =l_oSelectedRow.cells[l_iCB].innerHTML;

 }
```

Comment: Can you put a fiddle example?

Comment: jquery makes this pretty easy - can you use it?

Comment: yes I can use jquery but I want to get the property of the column. I can just get the innerHTML is there any property in jquery which checks the type ?

Comment: changed it to jquery but how to check if the column is a checkbox and that too its checked

Comment: @PSDebugger What do you mean by column? What exactly does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the checkbox and create a jQuery object out of it, you can use the [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to find the value of its 'checked' property.

`$yourCheckboxElement.prop('checked')` will return a boolean, `true` if it is checked and `false` if it is not.

Comment: I fixed it with this : 
if(l_oSelectedRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked == true){

Answer (score 0):

You can count checked check boxes with below codes.

```
var c = $(l_oSelectedRow.cells[l_iCB]).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```

and detect rows had checked check box.

```
if (c > 0) {
    // checked check box is existed.
} else {
    // checked check box is now existed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hbm5dL1f/2/)

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    $('#table').find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        var check = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        alert(check);
    });
});
```

Iterate through all the checked checkbox and get the index of the closest tr

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hbm5dL1f/4/)

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var index =$('.input').val();
    var row = $('#table').find('tr:nth-child('+index+')').find('input:checkbox')
    if(row.is(':checked')){
        alert(index);
    }else{
        alert('no check box check');
    }

});
```

IF you want to check the row if there is a checked check get the row number use it as selector then check that row if there is a checked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

A better (and easier) way to do this is like this

```
$("#imageResultsList tr").each(function(){
    var cb = $(this).find('input [type="checkbox"]');
    if(cb.prop('checked')){
        alert('Checked');
    } else {
        alert('Not Checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerys .prop function

See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
<label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />


$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/a26sw7ba/2/

In your case you could do the following with jQuery:

```
var l_iNoOfRows=$("#imageResultsList tr").length;

for(var i=1;i<=l_iNoOfRows;i++){
    var l_oSelectedRow =$("#imageResultsList tr")[i]
    var l_sCbColumn =l_oSelectedRow.cells[l_iCB].innerHTML;
    alert($(l_sCbColum).prop('checked'));
 }
```

Obviously replacing the alert with what ever statement needed to accomplish your goals.